# Play! CRUD module overwrite new view

Tags: playframework, crud

How do you overwrite the "new" view of the CRUD module, I've tried

```
$ play crud:ov {Project-Path} --template Posts/new
```

But I get the following error:

```
 $ app/views/CRUD/new.html not found in any module
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't the "new" functionality implemented in view `CRUD/blank` and not `CRUD/new`? In that case, the correct command would be:

```
$ play crud:ov {Project-Path} --template Posts/blank
```